# changed directory permissions of 

Tags: ftp, chmod

So, I was changing some file permissions using gFTP, and somehow I managed to set the permissions of .. (idk how, last time I use gFTP)
The problem is I was working in the highest directory I could access. The log looks something like this:

> SITE CHMOD 0 ..
>
> 200 SITE CHMOD command successful

I now can't log into my site using gFTP or using plain ftp. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to fix the issue, or do I have to talk to the guy who hosts the site? Given that it is hosted for free, I would like to avoid bugging him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have SSH access you should be able to log in and change permissions, since you are (usually) the owner of your home directory. If not, you'll have to bug the administrator.